# GWT best way to implement admin console

Tags: java, security, gwt, web-applications, web

I am creating a GWT application and wish to add an Admin console.

My first attempt was to create an admin window (widget) and then just show it when the admin is logged-in.

The trouble with this approach is that every user accessing my page downloads the javascript responsible to show and operate the admin console - I don't like this idea, both for performance and security reasons.

As the admin console is just a "window" inside my application - I wish to download it only if the user is logging in as an admin and "purge" it when he logs out.

what is my available options to achieve that using GWT?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code splitting is the quick-n-dirty solution to move the admin stuff out of client-facing JS; however, anyone adept w/ gwt will know how to access code splits that were not downloaded.

The truly secure option is to run a second entry point and compile just for the admin.  That way, your server can avoid serving anything which touches admin functionality whatsoever.

It would also be wise to put all admin functionality into a package not allowed in your main compile; that way, you will never, ever leak unsecured resources.

Comment: let me check if i understand it correctly, i have a main build - this is the page that every client is loading, when a client logging in as an admin i am redirecting him to a different page which looks like the normal user page but with admin console link, this page is actually a different compiled gwt module, am i right? if so how can i not allow users to just open the admin enabled page on the first place?

Comment: Yes, if you want to have a second entry point that has everything in the first one, you'll want to change your first entry point to put everything but the `<entry-point ...>` into a different .gwt.xml, say, Inherit.gwt.xml.  So, main entry point inherits com.foo.Inherit, and adds client entry point.  Admin entry point can inherit the same common module, extend client entry point, and add admin functionality.

Comment: As for security, that's pretty much on you, depending on your server environment.  A poor man's security method is to build a trap into your admin entry point.  Delay calling the app load up until a secret password is entered into a text field.  This will get you some runtime security, though a good hacker could look up the string key you are testing against.  Better to send a hashed value.  That is, use some kind of string manipulation to obfuscate the value.  You could even just use a bunch of chars that you + together, just so the whole password is not in plain text for all to see.

Comment: Really though, you want server-side security.  If you go with poor-mans version, at least validate the password on the server instead of in the client.  (once again, sending unencoded passwords is bad for business).  The best bet is to have the page itself served over https with a login authorization flow that will only give the admin page to someone verified logged in as admin.  You can roll your own with a simple web form, just make damned sure you hash up your passwords before sending them over the wire, or a man-in-the-middle will gain access easily.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Ajax' solution, a few more details & options:

- Your Admin module is a different java project deployed in a different war, say admin.war.
- Your Admin java project inherits from your main project, hence you have all common functionality + Admin functionality.
- You Admin module javascript is accessible only from the admin.war web application, say index.html therein.
- Your admin.war web application is accessible only through local host behind a ssl tunnel. This way only those admin users having access to your server with a private key can access your admin module after having successfully opened up the tunnel, nobody else.  This option is super secure -- you control who has access and on top of it, all communications are encrypted.  But this option is applicable only if you have few admin users with strict control of them through their public keys your server authorizes.  Otherwise, I suppose you have to resort to the aforementioned authentication mechanism through password and code-splitting.

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate View with its own Activity for Admin console. You can use [Activities and Places design pattern](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) for this.

Also, you can use [code-splitting](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting) to make sure that only admins load the code necessary for the Admin console.

EDIT:

In your entry point class you should check if a user is authenticated and is admin and allow or not allow access to this part of your app. You should do the same on a server-side too. When a user logs off, close the app.

Comment: nice, but how can i force the loaded code to "purge" when the user is log off? should i cause a refresh for all the page - so that the code will get downloaded again without the admin part?

Comment: In your entry point class you can (and should!) check if a user is authenticated and is admin and allow access to this part of your app or not allow access. You should do the same on a server-side too. When a user logs off, close the app.

Comment: By the way, the code is not "downloaded again" when you refresh the page - it is cached by browsers. But there is no harm in having this admin code cached - it won't be accessible/usable if authentication checks fail.